# Synonym für "ob"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonym

Das Wort "ob" kann zwei Bedeutungen/Verwendungszwecke haben, siehe Duden [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ob_Praeposition) (Präposition) und [hier](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ob_Konjunktion) (Konjunktion). Wenn ich nun einen Satz wie folgt konstruiere:

> Man sollte sich **ob** der Ironie fragen **ob** ...

welche Optionen habe ich das zweite "ob" durch ein Synonym zu ersetzen? Zwei "ob" in dem Satz laufen meinem Sprachgefühl zuwider, aber mir will auch partout kein passender Ersatz einfallen.

Logischerweise könnte man immer den Satz umstellen und -formulieren, bspw.:

> **Aufgrund** der Ironie sollte man sich fragen **ob** ...

aber ich bin an einer Alternative im Original interessiert, falls es denn eine gibt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mir würde hier nur

> Man sollte sich ob der Ironie fragen, inwieweit …

einfallen. Ob es passt, dürfte aber stark vom Rest des Satzes abhängen.

Comment: ist regional, lieber nicht verwenden

Comment: @falkb Was ist regional? "in wie weit" (eigentlich "inwieweit") jedenfalls nicht.

Comment: @falkb: dann überschneidet sich wohl die Region im Falle von Bummi und mir? (Deutschland? ;)) ... ich finde "inwieweit" in der Tat angenehm, aber gerade hier auf dieser Seite merkt man immer wieder wie sehr sich lokale Eigenheiten unterscheiden.

Comment: das `ob` in der ersten Position des Satzes meinte ich

Comment: @falkb: das ist veraltet, nicht regional, siehe Links in meiner Frage.

Answer (score 9):

Eher denn das zweite *"ob"* empfehle ich das erste *"ob"* zu ersetzen, denn im der Verwendung als Präposition in *"ob der Ironie"* ist es außerhalb der Schweiz nicht mehr sehr gebräuchlich (laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ob_Praeposition) "gehoben, veraltend").

Eine synonyme Bedeutung erreicht man im Beispielsatz mit *"[angesichts](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/angesichts_Hinblick_Praeposition)"*, also

> Man sollte sich **angesichts** der Ironie fragen, ob ...

Comment: Oder einfach *wegen*, wie es der Duden ja schon definiert.

Comment: ich war versucht ebenso antworten, allerdings empfand ich die Bedingung `welche Optionen habe ich das zweite "ob" durch ein Synonym zu ersetzen` als verbindlich.

Comment: @bummi: angesichts dieser Bedingung verdient Deine Antowrt also mein Upvote von Herzen :)

Comment: @Takkat: danke. Ich empfinde übrigens "Eher **denn** das zweite" äußerst ... ähem ... ungewöhnlich als Formulierung (kenne nur "eher als").

Comment: @Em1: stimmt, aber ich finde "angesichts" zumindest passender in dem Kontext. Formal ist wohl beides machbar.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: ja schon klar, mir ist *"eher als"* auch geläufiger, aber wir waren ja bei der gehobenen, veraltenden Sprache... ;P

Comment: @0xC0000022L Hier im Kontext passt *angesichts* in der Tat. Beachte aber, dass hier eine kleine Verschiebung in der Konnotation stattfindet. Versuch mal *angesichts* bei den beiden Dudenbeispiele einzusetzen. Passt nicht. Dort würdest du dann doch eher zu *wegen* tendieren, oder *aufgrund*, wie du es selbst schon in deiner Frage vorschlägst. Die Wörter *ob*, *wegen* und *aufgrund* beschreiben die fundamentale Ursache. *Angesichts* macht dies nicht. Das ist eher "Betrachtet man mal die Ironie, dann ..."

Comment: @Em1: genau richtig - es hängt vom Kontext ab, wie man "ob" ersetzt. Deshalb habe ich auch *"im Beispielsatz"* hinzugefügt.

Answer (score 6):

Die Konjunktion `ob` hat keine Synonyme. `Inwiefern` und `inwieweit` drücken zwar ähnliche aber hinreichend verschiedene Sachen aus:

- `ob` bezieht sich auf das tatsächliche Eintreffen des beschriebenen Ereignisses/Zustandes insgesamt
- `inwieweit` und `inwiefern` beziehen sich auf diejenigen Eigenschaften/Teilereignisse/Bedingungen des beschriebenen Ergebnisses/Zustandes, die tatsächlich eintreffen

Unter Beibehaltung der Struktur des Satzes lässt sich also nur die Präposition `ob` sinnerhaltend ersetzen.